# C++ std::array don't work on my local compiler

Tags: c++, arrays

I follow this example [array::size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/size/), but it's don't work on my Dev C++ IDE, and I don't know why.

I tried to run on Code Blocks but it's still the same.
I think code is correct but how to fix this problem

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void useArray()
{
     array<int,4> myInts;
     myInts[0]=1;
     cout<<"Size of Array: "<<myInts.size();
}

int main() 
{
    useArray();
    system("pause");    
}
```

And this is compiler error:[image: error]

Comment: `std::array` is in C++11, and your link does say that, although referring to C++11 as the "latest revision of the standard" is wrong.

Comment: the error messages suggest you're not using a C++11-compliant implementation

Comment: @chris How to known version of my C++ and how to update to C++11

Comment: C++xx is the standard, not version. You cannot update it as it depends on the compiler. Read the compiler manual for the standards supported. Use another compiler instead

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` is C++11 only. Dev-C++ does not support C++11.

If you're just looking for options to Visual Studio this article is the right starting place: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/36vU7k9E/

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you're using a compiler that does not support C++11 (using the flag: **-std=c++11**) you always have the chance to use a Boost alternative.

Boost comes with the [Boost Array Library](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.array) which is an STL conform Array. The generated code will be similar to a C Array while having the opportinity to use additionnal methods on it e.g determinate the array size. All this basically works as the C++11 version of an Array.

It lives in the *'boost'* namespace instead of *'std'* therefore you need to include the following header to use it:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
```

You should then set a typedef declaration for the Boost Array:

```
typedef boost::array<std::string, 3> array; 
// The 3 stands for the number of elements the array can hold
```

Implementing one of these Arrays is then fairly simple:

```
array a;
```